# array of session variables

Tags: php, session

How can I create an array which stores numerous session variables? This is what I have so far.

```
$data = array(
'description' => $_POST['description']
);
echo $data['description'];
```

I would like the `$data` variable to represent the session variable so in the future I can call `$_SESSION['variable_name_here']` instead of `$data['variable_name_here']`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should start with the manual: http://www.php.net/session_start

Answer (score 0):

You ave to use `session_start()` in each page or place this line in template `header` file.
Then assign data to session

```
$_SESSION = $data;
```

So you can use like `$_SESSION['variable_name_here']`.

For more detail about session in php, refer this link:

https://www.php.net/session_start

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION is already an array, and so it can already store numerous session variables.

If you want to reference $_SESSION by a different name use the following:

```
$data = &$_SESSION;
```

Now `$data['example']` is equal to `$_SESSION['example']` as they point to the same place.